# Remove route from routing table by position

Tags: linux, routing, route

I know how to delete a route from a routing table providing all of the route's details (`ip r d ...`).

Is there any way to list routing table with some kind of indexes and then delete from its positions by the index?

Comment: are you looking for a guided delete operation ? Like it gives you some numbered lines with one route on each and you select the line number to delete ? If so, it is not available by widely used system tools. But writing a small script should not be too hard I suppose

Comment: script will do the trick

Comment: @MelBurslan yes, that's what I am looking for. Looks like writing a script is the way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple bash script which takes advantage of the builtin `select` command to present a menu.

```
#!/bin/bash
mapfile -t routes <<<"$(ip route)"
select var in "${routes[@]}"
do   [ -n "$var" ] && sudo ip route del $var
done
```

It reads the current routes into array `routes`, then `select` presents these in a menu, eg:

```
1) default via 192.168.0.254 dev p4p1 
2) 169.254.0.0/16 dev p4p1  scope link  metric 1002 
3) 169.254.0.0/16 dev p4p2  scope link  metric 1003 
#?
```

To the prompt `#?` you type the line to delete, eg `1` and return. This sets `var` to the string shown next to the `1)`, to which is prepended the `sudo ip route del` command. Type an end-of-file <kbd>control-d</kbd> to end.